# How to use the youtube api sample code in php?

Tags: php, api, youtube

So my question is as follows: I am trying to use the add_channels code sample from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

I went ahead and made an API key, along with both an OAuth client ID and secret. I am trying to run this locally only using xampp, which is where I stored the git repo they have as an example. So xampp/htdocs/youtubeAPI/sample-apps/php

However, everytime I run it I get:

```
Authorization Required

You need to authorize access before proceeding.
```

What authorization? I added the full path to my authorized redirect URIs: http://localhost/youtubeAPI/api-samples/php/add_channel_section.php what more do they need? I am somewhat lost as to how to use this API since our professor explained it by showing a youtube video of it at work and that's about it.

Comment: I haven't used this API yet. But my guess would be that it your client-id is linked, like with recaptcha, to your domain (something you don't have when localtesting) of course. I would recommend testing this project on a remote server. There are a lot of free domains (.tk etc.).

Comment: I somehow got it to work by adding a few extra URIs, such as localhost/oauth2callback. However, now I get a "Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" Sometimes I wish the docs would not assume people know how to use their api right off the bat.